# within is not necessary,spring aop.execution(* concert.Performance.perform(..)) && within(concert.*)

Tags: java, spring, aop, execution

In the book "spring in action",there is an aspectj expresssion:

```
execution(* concert.Performance.perform(..)) && within(concert.*)
```

execution() Matches join points that are method execution.
You  use  the execution() designator to select  Performance’s perform() method.

```
execution(* concert.Performance.perform(..))
```

within() Limits matching to join points within certain type.
you want to confine the reach of that pointcut to only the concert package.

```
within(concert.*)
```

But I think,left part and right part of the expression both matches join points,"* concert.Performance.perform(..)" indicates join points must be in one class "Performance",it is already in package "concert",so what is the use of "within(concert.*)"?
If it is an "or",maybe useful,but it is an "and".

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please look into this to improve your questions, especially regarding formatting and proofreading: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this case `within(concert.*)` is important and result will not be  the same as just with `execution(* concert.Performance.perform(..))`

execution it's matching for  methods.

within it's matching for types.

in this example you already has poincut execution -- for any parameter for method
perform with any access modifier and you add 'specific type' - `within(concert.*)`

so your poincut it's --

```
execution(* concert.Performance.perform(..)) && within(concert.*)
```

for *any return type* , for *method perform* *from class Performance* from `package concert` that consume *any type from package and sub - package concert*

in case if you have just `execution(* concert.Performance.perform(..))` it almost the same as for previous except that type can by ANY

Comment: still not clear, what is the benefit of adding `within(concert.*)` if you already have `concert.Performance.perform` in the `execution` expression